# Sparse Pandas dataframe goupby sum enforce casting to float32

Tags: optimization, group-by, memory-management, casting, numba

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_random_df(row:int=10, col:int=7): # generate random Sparse Pandas dataframe
    np.random.seed(0)
    d=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(row,col)).astype(np.float32)
    d[d < 4] = np.nan
    df=pd.DataFrame(data=d,
                    index=[f"ip{i}" for i in np.random.choice(range(max(row, 10)), row, replace=False) ],
                    columns=[f"col_{c}" for c in np.random.choice(range(max(col, 10)), col, replace=False) ],
                    dtype=pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32),)
    df.index.name='usr'
    return df

def get_concat(pdfs): # pdfs=[df1, df2,..., dfN]
    dfc=pd.concat(pdfs, axis=0, sort=True) # sort=True: sort columns
    dfc=dfc.astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32, fill_value=np.nan)) # after concat, there's still NaNs
    dfc=dfc.groupby(level=0) # groupby index: 'usr'
    dfc=dfc.sum(engine="numba", engine_kwargs={'nopython': True, 'parallel': True, 'nogil': False}) # original SUM dtypes: float64 NOT SPARSE! =>> problem!!
    dfc=dfc.astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32, fill_value=0.0))# after sum, we get 0s
    dfc=dfc.sort_index(key=lambda x: ( x.to_series().str[2:].astype(int) )) # customized sorting of indices: ip1, ip2, ip12, ...
    dfc=dfc.astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype=np.float32, fill_value=0.0))
    return dfc
```

I would like to concatenate several very large sparse pandas dataframes. As an example of concatenating two fairly large sparse random pandas dataframes:

```
df1=get_random_df(row=np.random.randint(low=2e3, high=5e3), col=np.random.randint(low=1e6, high=4e6))
df2=get_random_df(row=np.random.randint(low=2e3, high=3e3), col=np.random.randint(low=1e6, high=5e6))

df_concat=get_concat(pdfs=[df1, df2])
```

I noticed that `sum()` method in `get_concat` function returns `float64` which is quite time-consuming and memory intensive.

I used `numba` engine to benefit parallelization for faster implementation since default engine in `sum()` did not accomplish this sample example.

I can cast the type using `astype` but since it is executed sequentially, I get into memory issues for larger sizes. Here is the summary of my implementation:

```
pd.concat => cast (Sparse float32) => groupby => sum() => cast (Sparse float32) => sort index => cast (Sparse float32)
```

and detailed printing of each part separately:

```
elapsed_time [concat+float32]                        1392.3 sec
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 7006 entries, ip2611 to ip626
Columns: 4191807 entries, col_0 to col_999999
dtypes: Sparse[float32, nan](4191807)
memory usage: 122.9 GB
<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
elapsed_time [groupby]                               0.0010 sec
elapsed_time [sum]                                   4529.3 sec
Current : 138035.44 MB | Peak: 417264.41 MB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4315 entries, ip0 to ip999
Columns: 4191807 entries, col_0 to col_999999
dtypes: float64(4191807)                  # <<<<<<<< Problem >>>>>>>>>
memory usage: 134.8 GB                  # <<<<<<<< Large Memroy >>>>>>>>>
<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
elapsed_time [=> float32 sparsity: 0.71]             3040.4 sec
Current : 101547.83 MB | Peak: 254647.26 MB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4315 entries, ip0 to ip999
Columns: 4191807 entries, col_0 to col_999999
dtypes: Sparse[float32, 0.0](4191807)
memory usage: 95.8 GB
<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
elapsed_time [sort_idx+float32]                      3178.5 sec
Current : 101547.83 MB | Peak: 254647.26 MB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4315 entries, ip0 to ip4314
Columns: 4191807 entries, col_0 to col_999999
dtypes: Sparse[float32, 0.0](4191807)
memory usage: 95.8 GB
```

Is there any other efficient alternatives to enforce `sum()` to directly obtain the results in `float32` for lowering the memory consumption or is this a completely wrong approach?

Comment: Note that the sum of Numba is not as accurate as the Numpy one which is used by default in Pandas. Numba has an error of `O(sqrt(n))` ULP while it is `O(log n)` for Numpy. This is why Numpy tends to be slower. `sum` of `float32` values gives `float32` values in Pandas, Numpy and Numba (tested on my machine).

Comment: By the way, the compilation time of Numba functions can be quite big and it often worth it only on function taking a lot of time or if the function is reused multiple times. Parallel build are more expensive.

Comment: Last but not least, if you care about memory and already used Numba, then you can try to compute data on the fly using plain loops in a Numba functions. This significantly reduce the need for temporary data structures. It is generally also faster (at least once optimized) though more complex to implement.